# Unable to show 4 products in a row

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

[image]

Above is my shop page, I want to show 4 products in a row, But after adding filter for 4 columns in functions.php, This problem occur. **If somebody go to direct my shop page everything is fine, but if somebody open a category wise products its not showing well, because i also show sub-categories of the parent on shop page.**

Note: If i reduce the width upper 3 columns, This single product in a row shift on above row. But My requirement is, One row show only sub categories and grid show the products.

All the grid items are a part of same ul element, its class is products.

Help me plz.

Answer (score -1):

Please check your theme details. In your theme show detail about column write this column class in your div.

for ex:->Avada theme give class col-md-3.
         Product 1
         Product 2
         Product 3
         Product 4

It display 4 product in a row.

Comment: I m using Bigboom theme, I thing something wrong with sub category, because if i remove subcategories, it shows good